# current_user_can comma list vs OR (||) list

Tags: functions, actions

Can any help with this?

I like the ***comma separated version*** because it's smaller to write and easy on the eyes, lol, but I can't make it work.

```
//** WORKING - Works on the Checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents', 'pst_pdf_ceckout_page_button' );
function pst_pdf_ceckout_page_button() {
    if( current_user_can('administrator') || current_user_can('ABC') || current_user_can('LMN') || current_user_can('XYZ') ) {
echo '<a class="button bc-pst-pdf-btn" https://LINK TO FILE.pdf" target="_blank">PST Exempt PDF Form </a>';
} 
}


//** NOT WORKING - Won't show up on the Checkout page.
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents', 'pst_pdf_ceckout_page_button' );

function pst_pdf_ceckout_page_button() {
    if ( current_user_has_role( array('administrator', 'ABC', 'LMN', 'XYZ') ) ) {
echo '<a class="button bc-pst-pdf-btn" href="https://LINK TO FILE.pdf" target="_blank">PST Exempt PDF Form </a>';
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `current_user_has_role()` is [not](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=current_user_has_role&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-function) a WordPress core function, on the other hand there's  `wc_current_user_has_role( $role )` in WooCommerce where `$role` is a string, but 3rd party plugins are general off-topic.

Creating this function was closed as wontfix in this ticket: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624 where Andrew Nacin [summarized](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624#comment:10) it neatly:

> Roles are merely a grouping of capabilities that can be assigned to a
> user. Only capabilities should be checked, not roles. If you need to
> know specifically what role a user has, there are a number of ways
> using the existing API.
>
> A new function like this is ripe for abuse. We need people to check
> for capabilities, not roles, and having a current_user_has_role()
> function is just asking for them to do things wrong. We still haven't
> gotten people to stop checking for user levels, let's not go in this
> direction.

You use `current_user_can('administrator')` but also check out the notice in the `current_user_can()` [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/):

> While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is
> supported  in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce
> unreliable results.

You can always write your own function wrappers or helpers to make your capability checks easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll re-do some code and try my options. :)